# How to overlap multiple maps into a single one?

Tags: r, ggplot2, mapping

I have created 9 different world maps with ggplot2 with the following code, where each differs from the other and shows the distribution of each of the nine Variables at global level. Note that each pixel can be "identified" only by single Var:

```
    ggplot(aes(x = lat, y = lon), data = DF )+geom_tile(aes(fill = "Var1"))+ 
  geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),
               data = map_data('world'),
               fill = NA, color = "#515151",
               size = 0.15) + scale_colour_discrete(drop = TRUE) + country_shapes
```

What I want to do now is to overlay each of them  to have a final single map. But can´t figure out how to do that. Any suggestions?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTlNU.png)

EDIT
 here the dummy df:

```
structure(list(lat = c(154.7916667, 154.7083333, 153.9583333, 
152.125, 150.0416667, 150.0416667), lon = c(49.54166667, 49.29166667, 
48.95833333, 47.04166667, -22.20833333, -22.29166667), Var1 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 1.453369498, 1.458679557), Var2 = c(0.154323816, 0.210961819, 
0, 0.173637688, 0, 0), Var3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Var4 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Var5 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Var6 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Var7 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Var8 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Var9 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more with same sample example. It is a bit difficult to see what is it you want to do? If you have 9 different maps, how can you possibly overlay them?

Comment: @89_simple Added few lines. The idea is to get a final map combining the information of each single map. Clearer? ;)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

```
library(tidyr)
dat_l <- tidyr::gather(dat, variable, value, Var1:Var9)
```

If 0 means there is no data for a variable then simply remove the zeroes

```
 dat_l <- dat_l %>% dplyr::filter(value != 0)
 unique(dat_l$variable)
 "Var1" "Var2"
```

After removing all the zeroes, I am only left with `Var1` and `Var2`. So

```
  library(ggthemes)
  library(ggplot2)

  ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = dat_l , aes(x = lon, y = lat, col = factor(variable))) + 
  theme_map() + coord_equal() + 
  geom_path(data = map_data('world'), aes(long, lat, group = group), col = 
  'black') + 
   theme(legend.position = 'top', legend.title = element_blank())
```

[image]

I have tried to recreate the structure of your data to my understanding and merged them into a single long
dataframe.`my.df` below will have unique lon lat and value for 10 variables 'var1' to 'var10'.

```
  library(data.table)
  tempList <- list()
  for(i in 1:10){

    temp <- as.data.frame(cbind(runif(10,-10.85, 20.02),runif(10, 49.82,59.47)))
    temp$var <- paste0('var',i)
    temp$value <- i
    tempList[[i]] <- temp
  }

  my.df <- rbindlist(tempList)
  names(my.df)[1:2] <- c('lon', 'lat')
```

If you look at the `my.df`, you will see that it has random lat lon and each lat long has only one value of 
var which goes from 1 to 9. It is simply a long dataframe which has merged rowwise your individal dataframes
I then plot using ggplot as below

```
  library(ggthemes)
  library(ggplot2)

  ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = my.df , aes(x = lon, y = lat, col = factor(value))) + 
  theme_map() + coord_equal() + 
  geom_path(data = map_data('world'), aes(long, lat, group = group), col = 'black') + 
  theme(legend.position = 'top', legend.title = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: @thank you. I understand your thinking. still I can´t reproduce the same with my data. I just included a dummy version of my df. Its kind of frustrating knowing what you want to get but not getting it.. :/

Comment: Does a value of 0 has a meaning or simply it can be replaced with NAs?

Comment: I have edited my answer and used your data. See if this is what you intended to do

Comment: Thank you! I included all my 9 variables and it works smooth :)

Comment: great. happy to help. If this answered your question, then please accept the answer

Comment: I accepted the answer.. and I have something new to ask. I would like to changemy legenda into gradient legend. so that a value close to 0 is shown in the map "light" coloured and increase progressively reaching the highest level at pixel level. I tried some, but get some error, or it does not look as dsired. Any suggestions?:)

Comment: In order to accept the answer, you will have to click the tick mark next to my response. In order to change colours, refer to this `https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_gradient.html`

Comment: I did already accept your answer, only I do not have enough " reputation" and it won´t be publicly displayed. thx for the link. I shall have a look :)

Comment: it´s me.. again..I tried to look o that page, but I ma getting errors like: Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale and similar stuff. I also tried to include cut in the plot. without positive outcome